# ¿Cómo puedo transformar milisegundos a segundos con un solo decimal?

Tags: java

Aquí en el código que se ve en la imagen el "timeleft" me devuelve por ejemplo "15923 milisegundos", y eso lo transformo a segundos con DurationFormatUtils "15,923 segundos". El problema es que quiero los segundos con solo un decimal "15,9 segundos", qué puedo hacer?
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: El código de tu pregunta debe ser añadido como texto, no como imagen, para poderlo replicar fácilmente y que te den respuesta.

Comment: No veo ninguna imagen. :(

Comment: Puedes dividir los milisegundos por 1000 y usando `String.format("%.1f", tiempo)` se mostrará solo un decimal. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax

Comment: Edita tu publicación , eliminando la imagen. Copiando tu código y  pégalo en tu publicación para que otros colaboradores puedan ayudarte

Answer (score 0):

Si solo desea mostrar (y no usar esto más para los cálculos), puede usar el código:

```
double d = 15,923;
new DecimalFormat("#,##").format(d);
System.out.println(d);
```

o

```
double d = 15,923;    
System.out.println(String.format("%.1f", d));
```

Si desea hacer cálculos, puede usar `Math.floor` para redondearlo